# NetCut Alternative For Mac OS X

Tags: applications

Any NetCut like app available for Mac OS X?
I wonder if there are available alternative out there to scan and cut all devices that in our LAN connection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[JamWiFi](https://github.com/unixpickle/JamWiFi) is an open source project that allows you limit user sessions on your WiFi network.

> JamWiFi allows you to select one or more nearby wireless networks, thereupon presenting a list of clients which are currently active on the network(s). Furthermore, JamWiFi allows you to disconnect clients of your choosing for as long as you wish.